# llvm build issue while cross compiling

Tags: llvm, cross-compiling, llc

I am trying to cross compile llvm from windows using cygwin to a linux like x86 architecture. I am using cmake of windows from cygwin becuase I had some issues with path while using cygwin cmake. I am facing the following error,

```
make[3]: *** No rule to make target 'NATIVE/bin/llvm-min-tblgen.exe', needed by 'include/llvm/TargetParser/RISCVTargetParserDef.inc'.  Stop.
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:6501: include/llvm/TargetParser/CMakeFiles/RISCVTargetParserTableGen.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:15989: tools/llc/CMakeFiles/llc.dir/rule] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:4648: llc] Error 2
```

Can you suggest some ways to solve this?

Comment: Try Ninja instead of Make. I'd also stay away from Cygwin for this.

Comment: Wsl is likely to be much better solution for you than cygwin, otherwise msys2 is also likely better. There are very few use cases for cygwin these days

Comment: ① If you're new to LLVM, don't cross-compile. Spend a while becoming familiar with it on one platform first. ② Cross-compile from a similar platform (unless you're doing this to catch and fix bugs related to cross-compilation in LLVM). When you run into a problem you'll want the ability to compile for your own platform and see if the bug persists, so make your own platform be similar to the key platform. ③ Avoid cygwin anyway (again, unless you want to catch and fix LLVM bugs). The LLVM developers aren't a cygwin crowd.

Answer (score 0):

while cross compiling NATIVE/bin/llvm-min-tblgen.exe is generated natively using the compilers of the host system and in my case it was using cross compilers itself and hence it was generating NATIVE/bin/llvm-min-tblgen which cause the search for .exe to fail. so my workaround was to use vs code to generate native components and then add them in appropriate directories.